# Отсчет времени

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Здравствуйте.

Используемые средства Delphi 7, DBD бд типа Paradox. Имеется бд с полями ID, название, дата регистрации, дата окончания. К примеру, 1 Fox 10.02.2011 10.03.2012, то есть срок действия продукта истекает через год. Суть состоит в том, чтобы через год шел отсчет по времени с момента и до конца, выскакивало сообщения типа срок действия истек. Я честно без понятия, как это делается, знаю, что используется компонент таймер.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @Павел Борщёв, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось. Сейчас вы идете в противоположном направлении и давите на жалость.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Уважаемый [[@Павел Борщёв](/users/4924/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%89%D1%91%D0%B2)](/users/4924/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%89%D1%91%D0%B2),

1. Все-таки, надо Вам исправлять грамматику, потому что человек - брезглив, и не каждый станет читать такую галиматью и разбираться в Ваших клинописях.
2. Теперь по существу вопроса (уж больно он жалобно прозвучал): Builder предоставляет возможность создавать в интерфейсе Вычисляемые Поля(Calculated Fields). Эти поля не содержатся в таблицах БД и являются виртуальными. Они заполняются во время запроса(но не упоминаются в его тексте). После очередного продвижения курсора возникает событие OnCalcFields, в обработчик которого и вставляется код, обеспечивающий сравнение сегодняшней даты и даты срока годности. Если сегодняшняя больше, то это поле можно заполнить подходящей строкой и, даже, закрасить его каким-нибудь тревожным цветом.

Удачи. "Учиться хорошо - легче, чем плохо!"

Comment: насчет грамматики вы правы,учту в будущем.А за ответ спасибо.Буду разбиратся что да как.